# What does Scope Bound Resource Management(SBRM) mean?

Tags: c++

I have been learning C++ these days and sometimes I heard about the term  “Scope Bound Resource Management”. What does Scope Bound Resource Management mean?

Comment: If you have a class that creates the resource in its constructor and destroys the resource in its destructor and you create a local variable of that type the resource will be managed based on the scope of the object - the resource will be destroyed when the object foes out of scope.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii  (Not exactly a duplicate due to the other terminology. But on the other hand it's the second google result for "What does Scope Bound Resource Management mean?" after this question itself.)

Comment: It's a better name of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is synonymous to [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). Since Bjarne himself says RAII is not a good name for the concept, some one proposed to use SBRM instead.

Comment: In the link you give, SBRM is a subset of RAII rather a synonym for it. RAII emphasizes that something somewhere owns a resource, while SBRM is the aspect of RAII related to nested scopes {}. A resource can however outlive a scope boundary by being assigned to a member of a class or return parameter.

Comment: @DwayneRobinson Can we say that the object has been passed to another (i.e. extended) scope?

Comment: @wilx Would you mind adding a reference to the source of the aforementioned statement by Bjarne?

Comment: @DmitryVolosnykh Yes, I would mind. This is not Wikipedia. Just watch his public appearances videos over the last 15 years. You will eventually find it.